# Objective C class extension. Not able to assign value to readwrite property

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C and learning Class Extensions using the IOS Developer Library. In the Customize existing class, I've been asked to create a readonly property and then also create a class extension with the same property as readwrite.

```
//XYZPerson.h
@property (readonly) NSInteger height;
@property (readonly) NSInteger weight;
   -(NSInteger) measureHeight;
   -(NSInteger) measureWeight;

//XYZPerson.m
@interface XYZPerson() //class extension
  @property (readwrite) NSInteger height;
  @property (readwrite) NSInteger weight;
@end

@implementation XYZPerson

-(NSInteger) measureHeight
{
    self.height = 100;
    return self;
}

-(NSInteger) measureWeight
{
    self.weight = 80;
    return self;
}
```

My objective is to assign the height and weight value. When I build I get a compiler warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'XYZPerson *const __strong' from a function with result type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')" When I run the program the height and weight values are 0;

Am I wrong with the syntax on assigning the values to NSInteger property?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSInteger) measureHeight
{
    self.height = 100;
    return self;
}
```

`self` is an object, not a `NSInteger`. Perhaps you want to `return self.height` instead?

The error message you're receiving is self-explanatory:

> returning 'XYZPerson *' from a function with result type 'NSInteger'

clearly means you're not returning the right thing.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a great tip! That removed the warnings. However, now when i try to NSLog the self.height and self.weight the result is still 0 (not null). My NSLos is in the same XYZPerson.m file. Any suggestions there?